# How to align text inside react flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-flexbox-grid

I am using [react-flexbox-grid](https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/) and my current layout looks like

```
const SpicyMenu = (props) => (

    <List>
        {props.foodItems.map(foodItem => <SpicyMenuItem key={foodItem.name} {...foodItem}/>)}
    </List>
);

const SpicyMenuItem = (props) => (
    <Grid fluid>
        <Row center="lg">
            <Col xs={3} sm={3} lg={2}><Avatar src={props.image}/></Col>
            <Col xs={6} sm={6} lg={4}>
                <Row around="lg">
                    <Col>{props.name}</Col>
                </Row>

            </Col>
            <Col xs={3} sm={3} lg={2}>
                <div>{props.price}</div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Grid>
);

export default SpicyMenu;
```

When I view this in browser, I see that text is not aligned in the middle of the box
[image]
[image]

My code is available in `menu` branch at https://github.com/hhimanshu/spicyveggie/tree/menu

What can I do to align the text in the center of the `Col`?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using `react-flexbox-grid` perhaps you can try [`.middle` as specified in the documentation](https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/)?

Comment: This somehow does not align items correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center align items, the parent div can use `align-items: center;`.

See example: https://codepen.io/amboy00/pen/GmpoLy